# How do I remove Azure network security config rules that blocked RDP and all SQL Server access on Azure VM?

Tags: azure-virtual-network, azure-vm

Azure network manager security configuration “NRMS-ZeroTrust...” created 54 inbound port rules on my Azure VM which closed my active RDP session and blocked all access to SQL Server.

Is anyone else having a similar issue with their Network Manager (preview)?  A screen print of my Azure VM Networking and Vnet Network Manager is below although in preview it looks like stackOverflow has blacked out the rule information you need to see.

[image: Network Manager screen print]

I have selected “leave preview” but this didn’t remove the rules.

I see the [Remove and update Azure Virtual Network Manager Preview components checklist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network-manager/concept-remove-components-checklist), but I have no idea what “undeploy the security admin configuration deployment” means as there is no link in the doc.  Unlike all the other Azure VM Networking Inbound Port Rules, you can't drill into or delete the rules created by the ZeroTrust config.  Creating a rule to explicitly allow the IP of my workstation is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

•   You can surely **‘undeploy the security admin configuration deployment’** that has been enabled by accessing the NSG (Network Security Group) of your VM. Also, as you stated that the ‘Zero Trust’ configuration deployed has blocked your access to the VM through RDP and to the SQL Server, it is as such blocked because the similar kind of rules have been configured on the Azure Network Manager with regards to the virtual network in which your VM is configured.

•   Also, a security admin rule allows you to enforce security policy criteria that match the conditions set. You can only define security administrative rules for resources within the scope of the Azure Virtual Network Manager instance. These security rules have a higher priority than network security group (NSG) rules and will get evaluated before NSG rules. Also note that security admin rules don't change your NSG rules.

[image: Evaluation preference]

Security admin rules can be used to enforce security rules. For example, an administrator can deny all high-risk ports or protocol from the Internet with security admin rules because these security admin rules will be evaluated prior to all NSG rules as that have been done with you.

•   Thus, to configure the security admin configuration to modify the Zero trust rules set for the network group of which your virtual network is a member, go to your **VM’s NSG** --> Under **‘Support + Troubleshooting’**, select **‘Effective security rules’**, in that check the name of the **‘Associated Azure Network Manager’** and select it, then select the **‘Configurations’** option under **‘Settings’**, in that check the security configuration rule collection set and modify the rules or remove them from that collection set and save it. Once done, you should be able to access the VM over RDP and the SQL Server over its ports. In this way, you can modify the **‘Zero Trust’** network configuration rules for a VM.

Please find the below snapshot of the above said settings in my tenant: -

[image: Azure Virtual Network Manager]
[image: Security Admin Configuration]

Please note that you need to have **‘Subscription Admin’** permissions to configure and modify the network manager settings. Also, refer to the below article for detailed configuration and deployment of Azure Virtual network Manager: -

https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2021/11/03/azure-virtual-network-manager.aspx

Comment: Thank you, @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT for such a detailed response.  I will walk through your instructions.

Comment: Hey @dbradish-gmail had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?